# $X,Y$ independent then $X+Y$, $X-Y$ independent as well?

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is simple: If $X$, $Y$ are independent random variables then $X+Y$, $X-Y$ independent as well?

Comment: @voldemort I loved those dots of yours!!

Comment: Sorry, voldemort: You're affirmative answer is wrong.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? (There were at least two downvotes. The total is now $-1$ after I up-voted the question.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Upvoted, but really -- "you're"?

Comment: @snarski : Your thee own lee won two point this out.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yah- for for some reason I was thinking that an invertible transformation of ind. rvs takes them to ind. rvs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not always.  For example, let, $X$ be the number obtained on rolling a die, and $Y$ the number obtained on rolling another die.  Then clearly $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  However, for example,
$$P(X+Y{=}\,6\,\hbox{and}\,X-Y{=}\,1)=0\ne P(X+Y{=}\,6)P(X-Y{=}\,1)\ ,$$
so $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are not independent.

Comment: A look at "a12345"'s "reputation" history shows that I am the only person who's up-voted this question so far. Will you consider doing the same?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes by all means, done.  It seems a reasonable question to me, can't explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
$$
\cov(X+Y,X-Y) = \var X -\var Y \\[8pt] \begin{cases} =0 & \text{if }\var X=\var Y, \\  \ne 0 & \text{if }\var X\ne\var Y. \end{cases}
$$
In the cases where this $\ne0$, the random variables $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ cannot be independent.

In **some** of the cases where this $=0$, they are independent, but as "David"'s answer has shown, not in all.